# Is there a way to make "mv" fail silently?

Tags: bash, mv

A command like `mv foo* ~/bar/` produces this message in stderr if there are no files matching `foo*`.

```
mv: cannot stat `foo*': No such file or directory
```

However, in the script I'm working on that case would be completely fine, and I'd like to omit that message from our logs.

Is there any nice way to tell `mv` to be quiet even if nothing was moved?

Comment: `mv foo* ~/bar/ 2> /dev/null` ?

Comment: Well yeah. I guess I had something "nicer" in mind, like some switch for `mv`. :) But that will do, of course.

Comment: I've seen some `mv` implementations support a `-q` option to quiet them down, but that is not part of the POSIX specification for `mv`. The `mv` in GNU coreutils, for instance, does **not** have such an option.

Comment: Well, I dont think the problem is how to keep "mv" be quiet, but how to do it more properly. Checking if there is any file/dir foo*, and user has writable permission, finally execute "mv", perhaps?

Comment: It might be a good enough reason to switch to some better scripting language, such as [guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [lua](https://lua.org/), [python](https://python.org/). All of them are interfacing [access(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html), [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html), [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html). And you could patch [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) for your needs. See also other shells, e.g. [zsh](https://zsh.org/) or [fish](https://fishshell.com/)

Comment: Some shells (notably [zsh](https://zsh.org/)...) accept plugins. You could write your own one doing what you want.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
$ mv  file dir/
mv: cannot stat ‘file’: No such file or directory
$ mv  file dir/ 2>/dev/null
# <---- Silent ----->
```

Comment: note, return value still != 0, therefore any `set -e` (which should be used in **every** shell script) will fail. you can add a `|| true` to deactivate the check for a single command.

Comment: @reto `set -e` should not be used in every shell script, in many cases it makes error management even more complex than it is without.

Comment: @ChrisDown I see your point. It is usually a choice between two evils. But if in doubt, I prefer a failed successful run, than a successful failure. (which doesn't get noticed until it's getting visible to a customer/user). 

Shell scripts are a big mine field for beginners, it's so easy to miss a an error and your script goes haywire!

Comment: @reto Much better to gracefully deal with errors than just dump out of the script.

Comment: @TrippKinetics if you use ```-e``` and forget about a corner case, then the script will just fail with a generic message. If you don't use it and forget about a  corner case, then your script continous and you have a very strange bug half a year later. But just use the appropriate technique for your task at hand, there's no "wrong" way.

Answer (score 18):

Actually, I don't think muting `mv` is a good approach (remember it might report you also on other things which might be of interest ... eg. missing `~/bar`). You want to mute it only in case your glob expression doesn't return results. In fact rather not execute it at all.

```
[ -n "$(shopt -s nullglob; echo foo*)" ] && mv foo* ~/bar/
```

Doesn't look very appealing, and works only in `bash`.

OR

```
[ 'foo*' = "$(echo foo*)" ] || mv foo* ~/bar/
```

only except you are in `bash` with `nullglob` set. You pay a price of 3x repetition of glob pattern though.

Comment: Minor issue with the second form: it fails to move a file named `foo*` when it is the only one in the current directory which matches the glob `foo*`. This can be worked around with a glob expression that doesn't match itself literally, tough. E.g. `[ 'fo[o]*' = "$(echo fo[o]*)" ] || mv fo[o]* ~/bar/`.

Answer (score 14):

`find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'foo*' -type f -print0 | xargs -0r mv -t ~/bar/`

— GNU's `mv` has nice "destination first" option (`-t`) and `xargs` can skip running its command if there's no input at all (`-r`). Using of `-print0` and `-0` correspondingly makes sure there wouldn't be a mess when filenames contain spaces and other "funny" stuff.

Comment: Note that `-maxdepth`, `-print0`, `-0` and `-r` are also GNU extensions (though some of them are found in other implementations nowadays).

Comment: Poige, a lot of our users don't use Linux. It is standard practice here, and very helpful, to point out what parts of an answer are not portable. The site is called "**Unix** & Linux", and many people use some form of BSD or Unix or AIX or macOS or embedded systems.  Don't take it personally.

Comment: I'm not taking anything personally. I though have an opinion that you've removed as I see now. So I repeat: I find those comments "note it's GNU" pretty pointless. They're not worth adding at all, first of all since my answer has clear indication that it's based on GNU version of `mv`.

Answer (score 12):

It's important to realise that it's actually the shell that expands that `foo*` to the list of matching file names, so there's little `mv` could do itself.

The problem here is that when a glob doesn't match, some shells like `bash` (and most other Bourne-like shells, that buggy behaviour was actually introduced by the Bourne shell in the late 70s) pass the pattern verbatim to the command.

So here, when `foo*` doesn't match any file, instead of aborting the command (like pre-Bourne shells and several modern shells do), the shell passes a verbatim `foo*` file to `mv`, so basically asking `mv` to move the file called `foo*`.

That file doesn't exist. If it did, it would actually have matched the pattern, so `mv` reports an error. If the pattern had been `foo[xy]` instead, `mv` could have accidentally move a file called `foo[xy]` instead of the `foox` and `fooy` files.

Now, even in those shells that don't have that problem (pre-Bourne, csh, tcsh, fish, zsh, bash -O failglob), you would still get an error upon `mv foo* ~/bar`, but this time by the shell.

If you want to consider it not an error if there's no file matching `foo*` and in that case, not move anything, you would want to build the list of files first (in a way that doesn't cause an error like by using the `nullglob` option of some shells), and then only call `mv` is the list is non-empty.

That would be better than hiding **all** the errors of `mv` (as adding `2> /dev/null` would) as if `mv` fails for any other reason, you'd probably still want to know why.

### in zsh

```
files=(foo*(N)) # where the N glob qualifier activates nullglob for that glob
(($#files == 0)) || mv -- $files ~/bar/
```

Or use an anonymous function to avoid using a temporary variable:

```
() { (($# == 0)) || mv -- "$@" ~/bar/; } foo*(N)
```

`zsh` is one of those shells that don't have the Bourne bug and do report an error without executing the command when a glob doesn't match (and the `nullglob` option has not been enabled), so here, you could hide `zsh`'s error and restore stderr for `mv` so you would still see the `mv` errors if any, but not the error about the non-matching globs:

```
(mv 2>&3 foo* ~/bar/) 3>&2 2>&-
```

Or you could use `zargs` which would also avoid problems if the `foo*` glob would expand to too man files.

```
autoload zargs # best in ~/.zshrc
zargs -r -- foo* -- mv -t ~/bar # here assuming GNU mv for its -t option
```

### In ksh93:

```
files=(~(N)foo*)
((${#files[#]} == 0)) || mv -- "${files[@]}" ~/bar/
```

### In bash:

`bash` has no syntax to enable `nullglob` for one glob only, and the `failglob` option cancels `nullglob` so you'd need things like:

```
saved=$(shopt -p nullglob failglob) || true
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -u failglob
files=(foo*)
((${#files[@]} == 0)) || mv -- "${files[@]}" ~/bar/
eval "$saved"
```

or set the options in a subshell to save have to save them before and restore them afterwards.

```
(
  shopt -s nullglob
  shopt -u failglob
  files=(foo*)
  ((${#files[@]} == 0)) || mv -- "${files[@]}" ~/bar/
)
```

### In `yash`

```
(
  set -o nullglob
  files=(foo*)
  [ "${#files[@]}" -eq 0 ] || mv -- "${files[@]}" ~/bar/
)
```

### In `fish`

In the fish shell, the nullglob behaviour is the default for the `set` command, so it's just:

```
set files foo*
count $files > /dev/null; and mv -- $files ~/bar/
```

### POSIXly

There's no `nullglob` option in POSIX `sh` and no array other than the positional parameters. There is a trick you can use though to detect whether a glob matched or not:

```
set -- foo[*] foo*
if [ "$1$2" != 'foo[*]foo*' ]; then
  shift
  mv -- "$@" ~/bar/
fi
```

By using both a `foo[*]` and `foo*` glob, we can differentiate between the case where there's no matching file and the one where there's one file which happens to be called `foo*` (which a `set -- foo*` couldn't do).

### More reading:

- [Why is nullglob not default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803)
- [this related discussion on the Austin Group mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg03982.html) (the Austin Group is the body that maintains the POSIX specification)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you are using bash, because this error depends on bash's behavior to expand unmatched globs to themselves. (By comparison, zsh raises an error when trying to expand an unmatched glob.)

So, what about the following workaround?

```
ls -d foo* >/dev/null 2>&1 && mv foo* ~/bar/
```

This will silently ignore the `mv` if `ls -d foo*` fails, while still logging errors if `ls foo*` succeeds but the `mv` fails. (Beware, `ls foo*` could fail for other reasons than `foo*` not existing, e.g., insufficient rights, problem with the FS, etc., so such conditions would be silently ignored by this solution.)

Comment: I'm mostly interested in bash, yeah (and I did tag the question as `bash`). +1 for taking into account the fact that `mv` might fail for other reasons than `foo*` not existing.

Comment: (In practice I probably won't be using this since it's kind of verbose, and the point of the `ls` command wouldn't be very clear for future readers, at least without a comment.)

Comment: `ls -d foo*` could return  with a non-zero exit status for other reasons as well, like after a `ln -s /nowhere foobar` (at least with some `ls` implementations).

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not the best but you can use `find` command to check if the folder is empty or not:

```
find "foo*" -type f -exec mv {} ~/bar/ \;
```

Comment: This would give a literal `foo*` search path to `find`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do for example

`mv 1>/dev/null 2>&1 foo* ~/bar/` or `mv  foo* ~/bar/ 1&>2`

For more details see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055

Comment: `mv foo* ~/bar/ 1&>2` does not silence the command, it sends what would have been on stdout to also be on stderr.

Comment: and if you're using mingw under windows (like me) replace `/dev/null` with `NUL`

Comment: How does this command work? What do the ampersands do? What do `1` and `2` mean?

Comment: @AaronFranke 1 is stdout and 2 is stderr pipe by default when a Linux process get created. Know more on pipe in Linux commands. You can start here -- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-i-o-redirection

Answer (score 2):

You can cheat (portably) with `perl`:

```
perl -e 'system "mv foo* ~/bar/" if glob "foo*"'
```

Comment: Please comment before downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use Perl, you might as well go all the way:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my $target = "$ENV{HOME}/bar/";

foreach my $file (<foo*>) {
    move $file, $target  or warn "Error moving $file to $target: $!\n";
}
```

or as a one-liner:

```sh
perl -MFile::Copy -E 'move $_, "$ENV{HOME}/bar/" or warn "$_: $!\n" for <foo*>'
```

(For details of the `move` command, see the documentation for [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html).)

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me for in case of a file, when you are in the source location.

```
[ -f ${fileName} ] && mv ${source}/${fileName} ${destination}
```

In case of a directory

```
[ -d ${source} ] && mv ${source} ${destination}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mv foo* ~/bar/ 2>/dev/null
```

Whether Above command is successfull or not we can find by exit status of previous command

```
command: echo $?
```

if output of echo $? is other than 0 means command unsucessfull
if output is 0 means command is successfull

Answer (score -1):

Instead

```
mv foo* ~/bar/
```

you can do

```
cp foo* ~/bar/
rm foo*
```

Simple, readable :)

Comment: Copying, then removing, takes longer than a simple move. It also will not work if a file is larger than the available free disc space.

Comment: The OP wants a solution that is silent.  Neither `cp` nor `rm` are silent if `foo*` does not exist.