# Set bad exit code in alias

Tags: bash

I am adding some aliases to .bashrc to discourage people from using standard commands where there is a more complex process involved in achieving the desired result. But how can I set the exit code in case the alias is invoked from a script? Ideally without generating a spurious error message like "no such file or directory" (I did find [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87605/is-there-a-way-to-make-mv-fail-silently), but surely there a cleaner way?)

e.g.

```
 alias useradd='echo "Nope....you should be using the custom script."'
```

should result in.....

```
 # useradd newuser
 Nope....you should be using the custom script.
 # echo $?
 -1
 #
```

Comment: So you want it to exit with an impossible code (`-1`)?

Comment: I want to to return a non-zero exit status - I may refine the exact error number - do you have a suggestion?

Comment: One of the numbers between 1 and 255

Comment: `fail(){ echo >&2 "$1"; return 1; }; ...; alias useradd='fail "no useradd for you!"'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a function instead of an alias.

```
useradd () {
  echo "Nope....you should be using the custom script." >&2
  return 2
}
```

See [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/237982) for more information on the limitations of aliases and usefulness of functions.

Also note that whether you use a function or an alias your users can bypass them by using the `command` builtin or simply escaping the command name like:

```
\useradd ...
```

Comment: You could also do both, `alias t='_(){ echo hi;return 0;};_'`